# Why doesn't search_columns argument work for get_posts() function in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin that requires searching post titles for a keyword.

According to the documentation for [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/), I should be able to limit my search to just the post title by setting the "search_columns" argument to 'post_title'. Unfortunately, this isn't doing anything. The results still contain posts where the keyword appears in the post title OR content.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a problem with Wordpress?

I'm using just vanilla Wordpress v5.9.2. My code:

```
function search_posts($keyword, $params) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => $params['type'],
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'draft', 'pending', 'future'),
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'search_columns' => array('post_title'),
        's'           => $keyword,
    );

    $matching_posts = get_posts($args);

    return $matching_posts;
}
```

Comment: Topically related: [How to use search_columns in WP_User_Query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/69543)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress 5.9.2, there isn't a built-in parameter within `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` to limit the search exclusively to post titles using `search_columns`. To work around this limitation, you can utilize a custom SQL query through WordPress’s `$wpdb` class.

```
function search_posts_by_title($keyword, $post_type = 'post') {
    global $wpdb;

    $keyword = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($keyword) . '%';

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title LIKE %s AND post_type = %s AND post_status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'pending', 'future')",
        $keyword,
        $post_type
    );

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    return $posts;
}
```